# Wire Mock : HTTP method PATCH doesn't support output

Tags: rest, selenium, jersey, wiremock

Trying to mock rest api PATCH using wire Mock

```
public void mockPersonUpdateService() throws IOException {
    stubFor(patch(urlMatching(".*/person-service-web/v1/person/*\\?access_token=38a307c9-487b-402a-bb32-83bacd53bcc1")).willReturn(aResponse().withHeader(
                "Content-Type", "application/json").withStatus(200).withBody(IOUtils.toString(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                            "json/peroson.update.json.response")))));

}
```

Getting below exception on running test case :

> Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: HTTP method PATCH doesn't
>   support output  at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector$4.getOutputStream(HttpUrlConnector.java:385)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:200)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:194)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:243)
>   at
>   com.ctlts.vantive.services.common.rest.client.AbstractJerseyLoggingFilter$LoggingStream.write(AbstractJerseyLoggingFilter.java:294)
>   at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:125)  at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableOutputStream.write(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:299)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1853)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.flush(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1034)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:462)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider.writeTo(JacksonJsonProvider.java:583)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
>   at
>   com.ctlts.vantive.services.common.rest.client.AbstractJerseyLoggingFilter.aroundWriteTo(AbstractJerseyLoggingFilter.java:259)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.doWriteEntity(ClientRequest.java:517)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:499)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:388)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
>   ... 57 more